# Will high houses count even if the villagers are not able to access them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Considering [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKVpb.jpg) or [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/File:Appartment_Complex.png) design with 3 levels apartments, do the doors/houses on the top floor count towards the village house count even if the villagers are not able to access them (via stairs for example)?

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft doesn't care if villagers are able to access the doors, it just cares that there *are* doors.

So yes, the doors/houses on top do count toward the villager house count.

Comment: Even if the villagers are all the lower level?

Comment: @Jefffery correct. Minecraft counts doors, regardless of where they are.

Comment: ryuzoku below is telling a completely different story though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Minecraft Wiki..

> Villagers will recognize a house within sixteen blocks along both horizontal axes, and up to three blocks above or five blocks below the level of the ground the villager is standing on

Therefore aslong as the following conditions are true:

1) floor below the top floor is reachable by villagers

2) it is 3 blocks or less above the previous floor

3) have more inside blocks than outside blocks

They should count as houses even without stairs.

Comment: Does village house recognition matter in the village house count?

Comment: Yes, that's what allows the villages to be dynamic. Each house recognized within the limit adds to the village house count.